# Padding-bottom for textarea isn't considered

Tags: html, css, forms

When I set a padding to a textarea, it works okay on the first look.
But when I type content that goes beyond the textarea height (when you start seeing the scroller) the padding-bottom ceases to exist.
Is there a way to fix this? It seems to be a default behavior.
You can see a very basic example here: http://jsfiddle.net/corinne/LKkky/
PS. Browser used is Chrome.
PS2. Just tried with Firefox and actually the padding stays.

Comment: Yes and you can't avoid it. Put the textarea inside a div and style that div, remove borders from textarea and et voila.

Comment: The padding is still there, it just drops below the bottom of the scrollable area as you type.  It would be the same if you had a scrolling div or even the body if the page has scrollbars.

Comment: I'm using Firefox 8.0 and I can't see where is the problem. No matter how much text I type in, the padding is always there. So maybe it's specific to the browser you're using.

Comment: @Shadowxvii just tried out with Firefox (am using Chrome) and updated my question. Still it looks weird, like the scrollbar is inside the padding. But that's still better that the Chrome one.

Comment: @Adriano thanks, sad solution, but solution nonetheless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chrome, Safari and Internet Explorer render the textarea paddings differently to Firefox and Opera. Now which of them render the textareas incorrectly? That depends on what you are trying to achieve because in truth none of them render it wrongly, they all add padding it just comes down to how they interpretated the spec.

No CSS property will fix this 'issue' so the only way you can get around this 'problem' is to add a container element to the textarea and give that a padding instead.

Answer (score 2):

**As of 2022,** there is now an easy fix called [`scroll-padding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-padding), which adjusts the area that the browser will scroll-snap to.

```css
textarea {
    padding: 20px;
    scroll-padding: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it does still exist; You just need to scroll down to see the extra 20px of padding when the textbox content is filled in. May I suggest **overflow: hidden**.

Comment: Yes, you're right, actually. But overflow:hidden just hides the scrollbar. And actually, it doesn't change the problem, I still have to browse down to see the padding.

Comment: I tested in jsfiddle chrome and when the content filled to the padding level and on to the next line, the focus dropped down, leaving padding at the bottom, but chopping off the top (not great without a scroll bar). I believe user mdk has the best solution for you. Thank you for sharing this question.

Comment: `overflow-x: hidden` works for me and vertical scrollbar is still available

Answer (score 1):

You may assign the style `font-size: 0;` to the `form` tag because the problem is that inside such tag there is a new line somewhere, that you need to avoid.

After doing it you should assign the right font-size to the component having the content, in the most simple case the text area.

Answer (score 0):

I now wrap my textarea element in a div element and then set the padding and border on that. The textarea now has it's border and padding to zero. Plus I hide the resize handle as well.

```
<label for="giftMessage">Add a gift message
    <div class="textAreaWrapper">
        <textarea name="gift_message" class="input-text" id="giftMessage" value="" placeholder="Add your message here"></textarea>
    </div>
</label>
<style>
.textAreaWrapper {
    border:solid 1px #ededed;
    padding:15px;
}
textarea.input-text {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    border:0;
    resize: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    color:#000000;
    resize: none;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the attribute border-button you can resolve in part this issue.

For example:

```
.textarea {
  border-bottom: 19px solid aqua;
}
```